# Click event using DataBinding Library inside Recyclerview's adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, kotlin, android-databinding

I am new to  DataBinding Library and using it in an adapter of recyclerview.I want to open another activity on click of an view and pass an id to it.

Below is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
            name="trainingPlanResponse"
            type="xyz.TrainingPlanResponse" />
        <variable
            name="presenter"
            type="xyz.MyPlansAdapter"/>
    </data>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvPlan"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/arrow_right"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/dp15"

    android:text="@{trainingPlanResponse.planName}"
    android:onClick="@{presenter.onClick}"
    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/dp5"
    android:textSize="@dimen/sp18"
    android:textColor="@color/black_variant5"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    />
</layout>
```

Below is adapter code-

```
class MyPlansAdapter(private val context: Context?, private val list:ArrayList<TrainingPlanResponse> ):RecyclerView.Adapter<MyPlansAdapter.ViewHolder>()
{

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder?, position: Int) {
        holder!!.binding!!.setVariable(BR.trainingPlanResponse,list.get(position));
        holder!!.binding!!.setVariable(BR.presenter,this);
//        holder!!.tvPlans.text=list.get(position).planName
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup?, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_myplans,parent,false);
        return ViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

   fun onClick()
    {
        val intent = Intent(context, PlanWeekActivity::class.java)
        context!!.startActivity(intent)
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)
    {
//        val tvPlans: TextView
          var  binding: ViewDataBinding?


        init {
            binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(itemView);

        }

    }
}
```

I tried using onClick from xml and getting below error-

> [kapt] An exception occurred:
>   android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding
>   errors.
>   ****/ data binding error ****msg:Listener class android.view.View.OnClickListener with method onClick did not match
>   signature of any method presenter.onClick
>   file:xyz/item_myplans.xml
>   loc:20:23 - 20:39 ****\ data binding error ****

Also I am not able to understand how will i pass planId to it?
My Model is-

```
class TrainingPlanResponse{
    var planId:String?=null;
var planName:String?=null;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to set a `View.OnClickListener` to your `TextView`. But the statement `presenter.onClick` should not be used for method references. Instead you should use the standard *Java* notation `presenter::onClick`.

The `onClick()` itself can't be used as a `View.OnClickListener`, since the signatures don't match. Functionally it's `(View)->Unit` vs `()->Unit`.

So either declare `fun onClick(v: View)` or use a lambda notation within your xml `@{v -> presenter.onClick()}`.

Comment: Thanks.How can i get position of item clicked inside recyclerview in above example using data binding..i.e. position inside onClick method?

Comment: You could put the position as a variable or means to retrieve it. Even better: bind the `ViewHolder` instead of the `Adapter`. There you'll have the positions.

Comment: "You could put the position as a variable or means to retrieve it."Can u give me a code  example ?

Comment: It's a followup question. Would you mind to actually put it as another question? You could drop the link so I can have a look there.